# Efficient way to write multiple file content into a single file

Tags: c, multithreading, algorithm, file, pthreads

There are n-number of files with vary in size. How we could efficently append the content of all the files into a single file?

Techniques or algorithm would help? Basically I am expecting efficent method to achieve this in c language.

Comment: What do you mean "efficient"? Minimum disk i/o? Minimum cpu load? Minimum memory use? Maximum parallelization? Something else?

Comment: @Ted Hopp I am mostly interested in time and cpus usage...

Comment: Check out Matt Ball's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Start simple. Multithreading will introduce significant complexity, and won't necessarily make things run any faster. Pseudocode time:

```
Create a new file "dest" in write-only mode.
For each file "source" you want to append:
    Open "source" in read-only mode
    For each line "L" in "source":
        Write "L" to "dest"
    Close "source"
Close "dest"
```

---

BTW, this is dead simple (and near-optimal) to implement using simple command-line Linux tools (`cat`, etc.), though of couse that isn't exactly portable to Windows. One-liner example:

```
for i in `find . -type f -name "*.txt"`; do cat $i >> result.out; done
```

(Find every `.txt` file in the current directory and append it to `result.out`.)

Comment: This should do the same thing in Windows (at least for text files): `FOR /R %i in (*.txt) DO TYPE %i >> result.out`

Comment: Let's just hope you have an SSD!

Comment: Why line by line in text mode?

Comment: @ruslik it was a semi-arbitrary decision. Primarily, it's simpler to write the pseudocode to read/write line-by-line than use buffering (which would make more sense in real code).

Answer (score 2):

Go through and find the total size of all of the files.

Then allocate an output file of that size, go through them again and write the data to your output.

Comment: What's the benefit of computing total file size?

Comment: @Mark: So that you can allocate a few big chunks of space for the result, rather than continuously appending in little pieces, forcing the file system to find a new place for the new chunk every time.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know you could tell the operating system how big the file would be, let alone from C.

Comment: @Mark: Yes... it's not quite part of the standard library, but see [`_chsize_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk925tyb.aspx) and [`_filelengthi64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfbc2kec.aspx), which you can use together with [`_fileno`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs6wbdhx.aspx) to get/set the length of a `FILE*`.

Comment: Or on POSIX systems, `truncate()` or `ftruncate()`.

Comment: @caf: Funny... I thought [`chsize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235502.aspx) was the POSIX version (as mentioned on MSDN)?

Comment: @Mehrdad sounds good, but how to guarantee that the file content would not loose. There is a chance for few overlaps/hole in middle of file etc. And how complex to implement this?

Comment: @Thangaraj: The file size is only a *hint* for efficiency. If it is too small, there will not be a problem; if it is too large, however, you will need to truncate the file to avoid zero bytes at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't what the contents of the files are or the purpose of appending them, this solution might not be the best if its just text or something. However, I'd probably find a zip library to use (either licensed or open source), then just zip all the files into a single archive.

zlib looks interesting: http://www.zlib.net/

Answer (score 0):

1. get the size Sn of each file and calculate the total size T of all the files
2. create the dest file
3. use mmap to map the dest file with the size T, you will get a pointer P to the start address of the memmap region
4. mmap each file to mem, and copy each data to the region above in order.
5. after that, you would get the dest file with all the data from all the files